# Upload large CSV file approx 10,000,000 records in mysql table also it contain duplicate rows

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to upload a large csv file approx 10,000,000 records in mysql table which also contain same or more no. of records and also some duplicate records.
I tried Local data infile but it is also taking more time.
How can I resolve this without waiting for a long time.
If it can't be resolved then how can I do it with AJAX to send some records and process it at a time and will do it till the whole csv get uploaded/proccessed.

Comment: You'll have to first explain this new number notation you've come up with.

Comment: is it a billion records or 10 million?

Comment: via ajax would be even slower. if you want the load infile commands not take so long, break up the csv into smaller chunks.

Comment: Through adjusting your commas, it seems it's a million? Is that correct? We need to know the scale on which we're talking.

Comment: yes it is correct. These are 10 million(10,000,000) records.

Comment: Walkerneo it's the Indian style of writing. 10 million = 1,00,00,000 = 1 crore.

Answer (score 6):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` isn't going to be beat speed-wise. There are a few things you can do to speed it up:

- Drop or disable some indexes (but of course, you'll get to wait for them to build after the load. But this is often faster). If you're using MyISAM, you can `ALTER TABLE *foo* DISABLE KEYS`, but InnoDB doesn't support that, unfortunately. You'll have to drop them instead.
- Optimize your my.cnf settings. In particular, you may be able to disable a lot of safety things (like fsync). Of course, if you take a crash, you'll have to restore a backup and start the load over again. Also, if you're running the default my.cnf, last I checked its pretty sub-optimal for a database machine. Plenty of tuning guides are around.
- Buy faster hardware. Or rent some (e.g., try a fast Amazon ECC instance).
- As @ZendDevel mentions, consider other data storage solutions, if you're not locked into MySQL. For example, if you're just storing a list of telephone numbers (and some data with them), a plain hash table is going to be many times faster.

If the problem is that its killing a database performance, you can split your CSV file into multiple CSV files, and load them in chunks.

Comment: Actually I'm dealing with the whitelist solution for mobile numbers in a call center, and I have to upload this much of data every day (duplicates rows are there).

Comment: @user969923: Sounds like you get to go for a combination of optimizing my.cnf if that hasn't already been done and buying faster hardware. The Serverfault folks can probably help you more with specifics.

Comment: How can I do with HASH TABLE. I have only 5 fields and only one is primary key (mobile number). Give me some example.

Comment: @user969923: A hash table, as in the data structure (sometimes called a hash map as well): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table Remember, that's if you're not locked into MySQL. If you use a plain hash table, with one of the many available libraries, its going to be at least a few orders of magnitude faster than MySQL. You're trading away a lot of flexibility and features for that performance, but you will definitely get the performance. (E.g., I'd expect the 10 mil row insert to be under a minute, maybe a few if its a lot of data with those numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
load data local infile '/yourcsvfile.csv' into table yourtable fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Comment: OP has said he's tried `load infile` and it's too slow. How does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your storage engine this can take a long time. I've noticed that with MYISAM it goes a bit faster.  I've just tested with the exact same dataset and I finally went with PostgreSQL because it was more robust at loading the file. Innodb was so slow I aborted it after two hours with the same size dataset but it was 10,000,000 records by 128 columns full of data.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a white list being updated on a daily basis does this not mean that there are a very large number of duplicates (after the first day)? If this is the case it would make the upload a lot faster to do a simple script which checks if the record already exists before inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '../upload/csvfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
```

Answer (score 0):

I was realize the same problem and find out a way out. You can check the process to upload large CSV file using AJAX.

[How to use AJAX to upload large CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367082/how-to-use-ajax-to-upload-large-csv-file)