# How to send a big amount of data with ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

I would like to send a big amount of data by using Ajax, php and Jquery and see the result each time has been added to the database in a div. I tried this approach but the requests slow down after ten thousand requests. I never did that before. please can you help me optmize the code ? i tried also to upload a csv file but when it's a big file it take too much time to be upload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#title').val('');
        $('#date').val('');
        $('#csvfile').val('');
        $('#result').empty();
        $(".loader").css('display','none');

    });

    $('#csv').on('submit',function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('.loader').css('display','inline-block');
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var date = $('#date').val();


        if(title.length == 0 ){
            $('#title').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#title').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
        }

        if(date.length == 0 ){
            $('#date').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#date').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
        }

        if($('#csvfile').val() == 0){
            $('#csvfile').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#csvfile').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
            var file = document.getElementById('csvfile').files[0];

        }

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);

        reader.onload = function(event){
            var csv = event.target.result;
            var rows = csv.split('\n');
            let data = [];

            const csvCleanUp = /("|\s"|\s)*/g;
            var headers = rows[0].split(';');

            for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++){

                var obj = {};
                var currentline=rows[i].split(";");

                for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
                    const header = String(headers[j]).replace(csvCleanUp,'');
                    const currentValue = String(currentline[j]).replace(csvCleanUp,'')
                    obj[header] = currentValue;

                }

                data.push(obj);

            }

            console.log(data);

            let nb = 1;
            let d = 0;
            var myInter = setInterval(function () {
                if(d < data.length){
                    data[d]['title'] = title;
                    data[d]['date'] = date;

                    console.log(data[d]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/admin/add/action/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: data[d],
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (resp) {
                            //console.log(resp.msg);
                            if(typeof resp.msg != 'undefined'){
                                $('#result').append('<span class="' + resp.color + '"> n° ' + nb + '<br>' + resp.msg + '</span>');
                            }
                            $('#result').animate({ scrollTop: $('#result')[0].scrollHeight }, 50);

                            nb++;
                        }

                    });

                    $('#clear').click(function () {
                        $('#title').val('');
                        $('#date').val('');
                        $('#csvfile').val('');
                        $('#result').empty();
                        $(".loader").css('display','none');
                        clearInterval(myInter);
                    });
                }


                if(d > data.length){
                    $(".loader").css('display','none');
                    $('#result').append('<span class="success">Fin d\'execution du script</span>');
                    clearInterval(myInter);

                }



                d++;
            },100)


        }



    });
});
```

Comment: what is a "big" file... computers does not understand big files but they do understand measures like Bit, Byte, Kilobyte... We need a little bit more information about what files are you trying to send to the server.

Comment: The reason your requests slow down probably has more to do with what the server is doing than the workstation. Optimising this is likely to make little difference. In any case, the fastest method overall to do this is to upload the file and let the server deal with it all. Why didn't that work for you?

Comment: the file is a 10 Mo file i tried to upload it with ajax but it take about 3 minutes to be upload. i already configure the php.ini for big files upload.

Comment: i think i found my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367082/how-to-use-ajax-to-upload-large-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

this is the other aproach i have used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#title').val('');
        $('#date').val('');
        $('#csvfile').val('');
        $('#result').empty();
        $(".loader").css('display','none');

    });

    $('#csv').on('submit',function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('.loader').css('display','inline-block');
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var date = $('#date').val();


        if(title.length == 0 ){
            $('#title').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#title').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
        }

        if(date.length == 0 ){
            $('#date').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#date').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
        }

        if($('#csvfile').val() == 0){
            $('#csvfile').css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
            $('#csvfile').css("border","2px solid #bdc3c7");
            var file = document.getElementById('csvfile').files[0];

        }

        var data = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/add/v2/action/",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function (resp) {
               

            }


    });
});
```